# Create new columns in a DataFrame using functions and reposition the new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like a review regarding the method I use to create the new columns and then reposition them in the correct place where they should be.

The new column called `total_matched_vls` should always be on the right side of the column called `total_matched`, which in the original CSV is at position `10`

The new column called `market_matched_vls` should always be on the right side of the column called `market_matched`, which in the original CSV is at position `12`

```python
import pandas as pd

def calc_back(df):
    if (df['result'] == 'WINNER'):
        return (df['odds']-1)*0.935
    elif (df['result'] == 'LOSER'):
        return -1
    else:
        return ''

def calc_lay(df):
    if (df['result'] == 'LOSER'):
        return (1/(df['odds']-1))*0.935
    elif (df['result'] == 'WINNER'):
        return -1
    else:
        return ''

def total_matched(df):
    if (df['total_matched'] < 1000):
        return 'centenas'
    elif (df['total_matched'] >= 1000) and (df['total_matched'] < 100000):
        return 'milhares'
    elif (df['total_matched'] >= 100000) and (df['total_matched'] < 1000000):
        return 'centenas de milhares'
    elif (df['total_matched'] >= 1000000):
        return 'milhões'
    else:
        return ''

def market_matched(df):
    if (df['market_matched'] < 1000):
        return 'centenas'
    elif (df['market_matched'] >= 1000) and (df['market_matched'] < 100000):
        return 'milhares'
    elif (df['market_matched'] >= 100000) and (df['market_matched'] < 1000000):
        return 'centenas de milhares'
    elif (df['market_matched'] >= 1000000):
        return 'milhões'
    else:
        return ''

filials = [
    [
        r'C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\csv\history.csv',
        'history_p&l.csv'
    ],
    [
        r'C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\csv\results.csv',
        'results_p&l.csv'
    ]
]

for a,b in filials:
    df = pd.read_csv(a, dtype={'market_id': str})

    df['back'] = df.apply(calc_back, axis=1)
    df['lay'] = df.apply(calc_lay, axis=1)

    df['total_matched_vls'] = df.apply(total_matched, axis=1)
    df['market_matched_vls'] = df.apply(market_matched, axis=1)

    col = df.pop("total_matched_vls")
    df.insert(11, col.name, col)

    col_2 = df.pop("market_matched_vls")
    df.insert(14, col_2.name, col_2)

    df.to_csv(b, index=False)
```

A brief example of the original CSV for ease of testing:

```
open_local_data,country,competition,match_id,match_name,market_id,market_name,runner_id,runner_name,status,total_matched,odds,market_matched,percentage,above_odds,result
2022-08-24 15:00:00,UY,Uruguayan Segunda Division,31684262,Uruguay Montevideo FC v Progreso,1.202440748,Match Odds,11076801,Uruguay Montevideo FC,OPEN,197.2,2.88,448.52,43.96682422188531,9.24460199966309,WINNER
2022-08-24 15:00:00,AT,Austrian Matches,31685733,SV Gerasdorf Stammersdorf v Dinamo Helfort,1.202453470,Match Odds,10299781,SV Gerasdorf Stammersdorf,OPEN,15.99,3.05,27.12,58.96017699115043,26.17329174524879,LOSER
2022-08-24 15:00:00,UY,Uruguayan Segunda Division,31684267,Villa Espanola v Sud America,1.202440560,Match Odds,58805,The Draw,OPEN,458.35,3.5,651.11,70.39517132281796,41.82374275138939,LOSER
2022-08-24 15:00:00,UY,Uruguayan Segunda Division,31684266,Miramar Misiones v Central Espanol,1.202440654,Match Odds,5300627,Miramar Misiones,OPEN,642.05,2.1,1075.66,59.68893516538684,12.069887546339224,LOSER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical antipattern is using apply when better alternatives exist (see e.g., [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38697404/pandas-explanation-on-apply-function-being-slow)). Vectorized operations can be several hundred folds faster than using apply, which processes the dataframe in a row-based fashion.

Looking at your functions, especially `total_matched` and `market_matched`, they seem to be the same function but applied on a different column. This is bad practice in general as you would have to maintain the same code in two places. Intuitively, a better idea is to write a function that accepts a column name to perform the same computation on different columns.

You don't say *why* it is important that columns appear in a specific order. Perhaps this for a human reader only, but it's probably not a good idea to trust on the *order* of columns. However, if we insist on it and especially if your dataset is large, it feels wasteful to pop a column and then reinsert it. Instead, you can just insert the columns directly into the place where you want them.

I'm omitting a few things and making a few assumptions:

- The `result` column will only either contain `WINNER` or `LOSER`. It's easy to handle a `DRAW` too, but I will let you do that.
- It's good practice to explicitly set the type of each column of your dataframe. I don't know or understand your data, so I will not do this. You are already saying that `market_id` is a string, but keep going and note that [categoricals](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) are very useful in this and typically result in smaller dataframes (in terms of memory) and faster processing.

To summarize, we could write your snippet as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def describe_matched(df: pd.DataFrame, inspected: str) -> np.ndarray:
    return np.select(
        [
            df["total_matched"] < 100,
            df[inspected].between(1_000, 100_000, inclusive="left"),
            df[inspected].between(100_000, 1_000_000, inclusive="left"),
        ],
        ["centenas", "milhares", "centenas de milhares"],
        default="milhões",
    )


example_data = StringIO(
    """open_local_data,country,competition,match_id,match_name,market_id,market_name,runner_id,runner_name,status,total_matched,odds,market_matched,percentage,above_odds,result
2022-08-24 15:00:00,UY,Uruguayan Segunda Division,31684262,Uruguay Montevideo FC v Progreso,1.202440748,Match Odds,11076801,Uruguay Montevideo FC,OPEN,197.2,2.88,448.52,43.96682422188531,9.24460199966309,WINNER
2022-08-24 15:00:00,AT,Austrian Matches,31685733,SV Gerasdorf Stammersdorf v Dinamo Helfort,1.202453470,Match Odds,10299781,SV Gerasdorf Stammersdorf,OPEN,15.99,3.05,27.12,58.96017699115043,26.17329174524879,LOSER
2022-08-24 15:00:00,UY,Uruguayan Segunda Division,31684267,Villa Espanola v Sud America,1.202440560,Match Odds,58805,The Draw,OPEN,458.35,3.5,651.11,70.39517132281796,41.82374275138939,LOSER
2022-08-24 15:00:00,UY,Uruguayan Segunda Division,31684266,Miramar Misiones v Central Espanol,1.202440654,Match Odds,5300627,Miramar Misiones,OPEN,642.05,2.1,1075.66,59.68893516538684,12.069887546339224,LOSER
"""
)


df = pd.read_csv(example_data, dtype={"market_id": str})
df = df.assign(
    back=np.where(df["result"] == "WINNER", (df["odds"] - 1) * 0.935, -1),
    lay=np.where(df["result"] == "LOSER", (1 / (df["odds"] - 1)) * 0.935, -1),
)

df.insert(
    loc=11, 
    column="total_matched_vls", 
    value=describe_matched(df, "total_matched")
)

df.insert(
    loc=14, 
    column="market_matched_vls", 
    value=describe_matched(df, "market_matched")
)
```